# Simple number-guessing game in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, number-guessing-game

I've been learning Haskell for 2 weeks now which is I'm very new to it.

I would like to have feedback on what is good/bad about my code and how it could I improve in learning functional programming paradigm.

```
{--
    Number guessing game
    -- Generate a random number between 1 and 100
    -- Ask the user to guess the number
    -- If the user guesses the number, congratulate them
    -- If the user guesses incorrectly, tell them if they guessed too high or too low
    -- If the user runs out of guesses, tell them they lost
--}

module Main where
import System.Random
import System.Exit (die)

message :: String
message = "Welcome to the number guessing game! \n\
          \You have 10 guesses to guess the number.\n\
          \The computer will generate a random number between 1 and 100.\n\
          \Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n"


askNumber :: IO Integer
askNumber = do
    putStrLn "Take a guess: " 
    input <- getLine

    let number = read input :: Integer
    if number < 1 || number > 100
        then do
            putStrLn "Number must be between 1 and 100"
            askNumber
        else return number


playGame :: Integer -> IO ()
playGame secretNumber = counter 1
    where 
        counter getTries = do
            let maxGeusses = 10
            putStrLn $ "You have " ++ show (maxGeusses - getTries) ++ " tries left.\n"
            guess <- askNumber
            
            if guess == secretNumber && getTries <= maxGeusses
                then do
                    putStrLn "You guessed the number!"
                    die "You won!"
                else if getTries < maxGeusses
                    then do
                        if guess > secretNumber
                            then do
                                putStrLn "Your guess was too high\n" >> counter (getTries + 1)
                                playGame secretNumber
                            else do
                                putStrLn "Your guess was too low\n" >> counter (getTries + 1)
                                playGame secretNumber
                    else do
                        die "You lost!"


main :: IO () 
main = do
    putStrLn message
    secretNumber <- randomRIO (1, 100):: IO Integer
    playGame secretNumber
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty good for your first project!
And it mostly works!

### Wall

Using the option `-Wall` will get the compiler to complain more about little ambiguities in your code, kinda like a linter.
In this case it alerts that it's filling in the type of `counter` for us; we can shut it up by adding `counter :: Int -> IO ()` right about it inside the where clause.

### Style

- Why is `counter` called that? It contain most of the game! Maybe you can give it a better name. If not, the traditional name for a recursive sub-function that does all the work is "`go`". (I don't like it, but it's convention.)
- Why is `getTries` called that? It's neither a function nor an IO.
- Using `>>` like that is kinda out of place. It's the same as just having the two expressions as seperate lines of the `do` block. That's what `do` is *for*, to safe us having to use lots of `>>`s and `>>=`s.
- On the flip side, it'd be pretty normal to skip the variable `input` altogether. Remember that monads are functors; we can just write `number <- read <$> getLine`. If you prefer `number :: Integer <- read <$> getLine`, you'll need to add `-XScopedTypeVariables` to your compiler options.
- The IO expression `counter` (renamed `go`) never "returns". I'll talk more below about whether that's good in itself; the point here is that it makes the recursive calls to `playGame secretNumber` unreachable. It's good to treat unreachable code as a bug and squash it.
- For a human-interactive CLI tool, it's nice to be able to edit the input before hitting enter. Poking about for two seconds *did not* find me a working off-the shelf solution, which is annoying but neither your problem nor mine.
- Be clear about what you're importing; either qualify the import or explicitly import just the names you want. This makes it easier for new people to figure out where stuff comes from.
- `maxGeusses` is spelled wrong. Also, move it up to the `where` clause so it's not cluttering up the `do` block.

### Behavior

- Why are you using `die`? That clearly shows up as an error (`*** Exception: ExitFailure 1`), which isn't appropriate even when the player looses. Probably `System.Exit` has some other command for non-failure exiting, but you shouldn't need it; just let the program finish naturally (*i.e.* let program flow get to the end of `main`).
- Be more careful with `read`, it will crash your program if it can't parse the string. [readMaybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) works. Actually *dealing* with the `Maybe` makes the function look pretty ugly. Finding pleasant ways to talk about things like failure is its own learning-curve in Haskell.
- While not technically wrong, it's kinda sketchy the way you're checking the number of guesses twice. A lot can go wrong in a recursive function; doing a thing right once is preferable. For example, as written, it will sometimes say you have 0 guesses left; what does that mean? In this case, we can do it all the way up as a guard on the definition of `go`.

Here's what I came up with while trying out all the above:

```hs
module Main where
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

message :: String
message = "Welcome to the number guessing game! \n\
          \You have 10 guesses to guess the number.\n\
          \The computer will generate a random number between 1 and 100.\n\
          \Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible."

askNumber :: IO Integer
askNumber = do
    putStrLn "Take a guess: " 
    maybeNumber :: Maybe Integer <- readMaybe <$> getLine
    maybe recurseIfUnparseable recurseIfOutOfRange maybeNumber
    where recurseIfUnparseable = do putStrLn "Only enter integers!"
                                    askNumber
          recurseIfOutOfRange n
              | n < 1 || n > 100 = do putStrLn "Number must be between 1 and 100"
                                      askNumber
              | otherwise        = return n

playGame :: Integer -> IO ()
playGame secretNumber = go 0
    where maxGuesses = 10
          go :: Integer -> IO ()
          go failureCount
              | maxGuesses <= failureCount = putStrLn "You lost!"
              | otherwise = do
                  putStrLn $ "You have " ++ show (maxGuesses - failureCount) ++ " tries left."
                  guess <- askNumber
                  if guess == secretNumber
                      then putStrLn "You guessed the number; you won!"
                      else do
                          putStrLn (if guess > secretNumber
                                    then "Your guess was too high."
                                    else "Your guess was too low.")
                          go (failureCount + 1)

main :: IO () 
main = do
    putStrLn message
    secretNumber <- randomRIO (1, 100):: IO Integer
    playGame secretNumber
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks a lot. Do you have a book that you recommend that I can read.

Comment: I'm not the person who wrote this post, but I really like "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" by Miran Lipovaca: http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: "Learn You A Haskell" is good; oldschool but well liked. Possibly too introductory for OP, but I don't know.

Comment: One small improvement would be to conditionally print "try" or "tries" to avoid printing "You have 1 tries left." Also, you mean, "even when the player *loses*," not "looses."

Answer (score 5):

Aside from what @ShapeOfMatter have already said. I'd suggest to force yourself into pure functions as much as you can. This is the way functional is design for.

Notice that when you make a guess you have four possible outcomes: Either you win, loose, guess too high or guess to low. You can express that as a enumeration (ADT in Haskell), then you can neatly define the `playRound` function which given the neccesary information produces a result.

What's left is calling that function over and over again, and produce the corresponding messages to the user, making the validations out of range and input should be a number. This is done via pattern matching easily.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

Module Main where

import System.Random
import Text.Read (readMaybe)   -- Check @ShapeofMatter answer for this

data EndGame = Win | Lose | TooHigh | TooLow

-- The pure function for one guess. Clear and simple
playRound :: Int -> Int -> Int -> EndGame
playRound numguess solution guess
 | numguess <= 0     = Lose
 | guess > solution  = TooHigh
 | guess < solution  = TooLow
 | solution == guess = Win

-- This function just executes playRound given users input. 
-- It makes some validations you can even factor out in other function
playGame :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
playGame guesses_left solution = do
    putStrLn $ "\nYou have " ++ show guesses_left ++ " tries left."
    putStrLn "Take a guess: "
    input <- readMaybe @Int <$> getLine
    case input of
      -- Input is badformed
      Nothing -> do
        putStrLn "input isn't a number" 
        playGame guesses_left solution

      -- Input is out of range
      Just guess | (guess < 1 || guess > 100) -> do 
        putStrLn "Number must be between 1 and 100" 
        playGame guesses_left solution

      -- Input is ok
      Just guess -> do 
        case playRound guesses_left solution guess of
          Lose -> putStrLn "You lost!"
          Win -> do 
            putStrLn "You guessed the number!"
            putStrLn "You Won!"
          TooHigh -> do 
            putStrLn "Your guess was too high"
            playGame (guesses_left - 1) solution
          TooLow -> do 
            putStrLn "Your guess was too low"
            playGame (guesses_left - 1) solution

message :: String
message = "Welcome to the number guessing game! \n\
          \You have 10 guesses to guess the number.\n\
          \The computer will generate a random number between 1 and 100.\n\
          \Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n"

main :: IO () 
main = do
    putStrLn message
    -- putStrLn "Set the max number of guesses:" 
    -- max_guesses <- readLn 
    secretNumber <- randomRIO (1, 100) :: IO Int
    playGame 10 secretNumber
```

## Edit:

Notice that guards can be used within pattern matching as normal guards, making code more succint. I didn't use it in the first solution because didn't want to introduce too much syntactic overhead. In general, whenever you find `if .. then .. else ..` you can substitute it with guards or with pattern matching on booleans. Many times it will improve readability, but not always... so just choose the option that reads better.

If you have nested `if .. then .. else ..` I think it is somehow a code smell. The rule of thumb which works for me is "don't use `if .. then .. else ..` unless it *clearly* improves readability". The reason for that is because branching is much more clear when you have many equations via guards or pattern matching instead of a huge expression in a single `if .. then .. else ..`

```
.
.
.
      Just guess 
        | guess < 1 || guess > 100 -> do       -- Input is out of range
            putStrLn "Number must be between 1 and 100" 
            playGame guesses_left solution
        | otherwise -> do                      -- Input is ok
            case playRound guesses_left solution guess of
              Lose -> putStrLn "You lost!"
              Win -> do 
                putStrLn "You guessed the number!"
                putStrLn "You Won!"
              TooHigh -> do 
                putStrLn "Your guess was too high"
                playGame (guesses_left - 1) solution
              TooLow -> do 
                putStrLn "Your guess was too low"
                playGame (guesses_left - 1) solution
```

Comment: thanks a lot this is very big help, I'm new to FP do you  have a resources  to recommend to dig deeper into FP like principles of this paradigm, concepts, etc

Comment: Nice use of [type application](https://zacwood.me/posts/haskell-type-application/) on `readMaybe`! Try help new people notice and understand cool features like that. I also really like the way you pattern-matched `input` with a guard to flatten out the validation logic.

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter thanks!, actually guards work within pattern matching as regular. I've added an Edit section explaining why `if then else` isn't a good idea in many cases. Also I provide a rewrite of the guard case so you can see there is nothing special with using guards within pattern matching ;)

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter oh! I was thinking you are the OP, sorry hahahaha. Still usefull edit though